# how to use vectors in this program (using string)? C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, justify

How would I use vectors in my current program; "use US dollar denominations 1, 2, 5,
10, 20, 50, and 100 in a vector."

```
int main()
{

    int i, dollar[7] = {0}, denom[7] = {1,2,5,10,20,50,100}, total = 0;
    string names[7] = {
        "1-Dollar bill",
        "2-Dollar bill",
        "5-Dollar bill",
        "10-Dollar bill",
        "20-Dollar bill",
        "50-Dollar bill",
        "100-Dollar bill"
    };

    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << "How many " << setw(5) << names[i];
        if(i == 0)
            cout << "s";
        else  
            cout << "s";
        cout << " do you have? ";
        cin >> dollar[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout <<  "You have" << setw(5) << dollar[i] << " " << names[i] << right;
        if(i == 0)
            if(dollar[i] == 1)
                cout << " ";
            else  
                cout << "s ";    
        else if(dollar[i] != 1) 
            cout << "s ";
        total += dollar[i] * denom[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "The value of all your bills is $" << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically my output looks like this = > "The value of all your bills is $"whatever sum input""

I've read my book and used youtube, but still can't quite fully understand how to use vectors on this assignment; also am I using "right justifying" correctly under setw(5)?

Comment: Just pointing it out: `if(i==0)
        cout << "s";
    else  
        cout << "s";`

Comment: Your lack of curly braces and indentation makes your code extremely hard to read. Especially that last `for` loop. I fixed it up for other StackOverflow people, but you should seriously consider using curly braces and consistent indentation for your own uses too.

Comment: I'm a beginner lol excuse my noobness. 

Should I take off the else statement then?

Comment: @enigmuz, My comment's snippet will output `s` regardless of the value of `i` as that's what executes if `i ==0` or if not.

Comment: you should mark john's answer as accepted. seems like it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

It couldn't be much simpler, replace

```
string names[7]= {
    "1-Dollar bill",
    "2-Dollar bill",
    "5-Dollar bill",
    "10-Dollar bill",
    "20-Dollar bill",
    "50-Dollar bill",
    "100-Dollar bill"
};
```

with

```
vector<string> names(7); /* note round brackets not square brackets */
names[0] = "1-Dollar bill";
names[1] = "2-Dollar bill";
names[2] = "5-Dollar bill";
names[3] = "10-Dollar bill";
names[4] = "20-Dollar bill";
names[5] = "50-Dollar bill";
names[6] = "100-Dollar bill";
```

Same with `dollar` and `denom` and you're done.

Comment: could have done with push_back and string concatenating with "Dollar bill" but needs integer to string conversion

Comment: Thank you Brendan, Chris, and John!

I went ahead and edited my code to

 vector<string> denom(7);
 denom[0] = 1;
 denom[1] = 2;
 denom[2] = 5;
 denom[3] = 10;
 denom[4] = 20;
 denom[5] = 50;
 denom[6] = 100;
 vector<string> names(7);
 names[0] = "1-Dollar bill";
 names[1] = "2-Dollar bill";
 names[2] = "5-Dollar bill";
 names[3] = "10-Dollar bill";
 names[4] = "20-Dollar bill";
 names[5] = "50-Dollar bill";
 names[6] = "100-Dollar bill";

However, for the dollar[7] = {0}; that I have, do I name the vectors  1,2,3,4,5,6,7? Sort of got lost in that step.

Comment: Well it should be `vector<int> denom(7);`. For the dollar vector, you ask the user to enter the values, so you don't need to assign them yourself, just `vector<int> dollar(7);` seems enough to me. The names of your vectors are `denom`, `dollar` and `names`, just like the names of your arrays. 0, 1, 2, etc are indices to your vector, not names. I guess what I'm trying to say is that, for this program, vectors are no different to arrays, and if you understand how the arrays work in this program you should also understand how the vectors work. It's only a slightly different syntax.

Comment: I edited the code as followed, but when I try to compile g++

I get this error message "hw2pr41.cpp: In function `int main()':
hw2pr41.cpp:46: error: `total' was not declared in this scope
hw2pr41.cpp:50: error: `total' was not declared in this scope
"

Comment: Do you have `int total = 0;` somewhere near the top of your code? I get the feeling that maybe you didn't write the program above, and you've just been asked to modify it?

Comment: jesus I feel like an idiot -_____- /// yes I forgot to add int total = 0. since I had originally everything in one int line I forgot to add it again.

Everything is working flawlessly now, using vectors YAY :D

And no, well we had to write something from scratch, I just didn't know how to implement vectors using the correct syntax.

Comment: OK, well there's quite a bit more to vector syntax as you'll no doubt find out. But in the program above they are just like arrays.

Comment: Also am I using the right justifying syntax correctly? I understand that setw(5) equals set width 5 etc etc, but say I want to right justify the denominations when they're being cout.
if that makes any sense. When I used << right or <<setw(5) I only manage to right justify the input the user has inputted.

Comment: I believe you only have to use right once (it's different from setw). So you only need to say `cout << right;` once and it will right justify for the rest of the program. If I understand you right you want to right justify the `names[i]` values? The problem there is that you haven't used setw before `names[i]` so there is nothing to right justify, so something like `cout <<  "You have" << setw(5) << dollar[i] << " " << setw(20) << names[i];`. Use that, add `cout << right;` somewhere before you do any output, and you should see everything right justified.

Comment: Yes!!! that worked!! I was fiddling with it and realized that the names[i] part was not being justified due to not having a setw() before it.

but the cout << right; before an output did the trick!

Thank you so much John! this is my 2nd week in C++ and your post is making me grasp C++ much more :) thank you!

Comment: @enigmuz Glad to help. I think you're making good progress in only two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int>dollar;             //This makes an empty vector of ints
    std::vector<int>denom;              //so does this. 
    int total = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> names;     //this makes an empty vector of strings.
    names.push_back("1-Dollar bill");    //push_back means add to the end of the vector
    names.push_back("2-Dollar bill");
    names.push_back("5-Dollar bill");
    names.push_back("10-Dollar bill");
    names.push_back("20-Dollar bill");
    names.push_back("50-Dollar bill");
    names.push_back("100-Dollar bill");

    cout << names[0]; //This prints "1-Dollar bill"
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started.